# evaluating a double integer series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

Consider the series $$\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(m,n)}{m^2n^2}$$. In addition, assume that the function $f$ is weakly multiplicative. Then, how could we evaluate the sum. In particular how can we relate it to the Riemann zeta function?

Can we rewrite the series as $\sum_{m,n}\frac{f(m,n)}{n}\sum_n\frac1{n^3}$ Is this justified. On the other hand, can we use infinite products here, since the function $f$ is weakly multiplicative

Comment: What is your $f$. If you meant $f$ is multiplicative both in $m,n$ then $f(m,n) = \prod_{p^k \| m} \prod_{q^l \| n} f(p^k,q^l)$ and it doesn't help, you need to add more restriction on $f(p^k,q^l)$.

Comment: @reuns Yes, it is multiplicative in both $m,n$, i,e., $f(ab,n)=f(a,n)f(b,n)$ if $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $f(m,xy)=f(m,x)f(m,y)$ if $gcd(x,y)=1$. By $p^k\|m$, i think you meant the max power of $p$ dividing $m$, right? And so I cant I right the whole series as an bi-infinite product, like just multiplying a $\frac1{1-p^{-2}}\frac1{1-q^{-2}}$ to your expression?

Comment: what is your $f$

Comment: @reuns say $f=lcm(m,n)$ or something similar, like $f=min(p)_{p|mn}(m,n)$

Comment: the least prime isn't multiplicative

Comment: @reuns ok! thanks, your answer is really great and on the dot! Anyway to see the sum combinatorially? Like, for example seeing it as the order of an element of cyclic group like in the case of $\sum_dd\phi(d)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $f(m,n) = lcm(m,n)$ then

$$\sum_{m,n} lcm(m,n)m^{-s} n^{-z} = \sum_d \sum_{m,n,gcd(m,n)=1} lcm(dm,dn) ( dm)^{-s} (dn)^{-z}\\ = \sum_d \sum_{m,n,gcd(m,n)=1} dmn (dm)^{-s} (dn)^{-z}=\zeta(s+z-1)\sum_{m,n,gcd(m,n)=1} m^{1-s} n^{1-z}\\ = \frac{\zeta(s+z-1)}{\zeta(s+z-2)}\sum_d \sum_{m,n,gcd(m,n)=1} (dm)^{1-s} (dn)^{1-z}\\= \frac{\zeta(s+z-1)}{\zeta(s+z-2)} \sum_{M,N} M^{1-s} N^{1-z}=\frac{\zeta(s+z-1)}{\zeta(s+z-2)} \zeta(s-1)\zeta(z-1)$$

Thus for $s=z=2$ it diverges as $\frac{\zeta(s+s-1)}{\zeta(s+s-2)} \zeta(s-1)\zeta(s-1)$ has a double pole at $s=2$.

Something similar holds for any $f(m,n)$ multiplicative in both $m,n$ such that $f(md,nd) = g(d) f(m,n)=g(d) f(m,1)f(1,n)$ for $gcd(m,n)=1$

Comment: thanks for the effort! I got it till third equality. Why did you split $\sum_{m,n,gcd(m,n)=1}m^{1-s}n^{1-z}$ into a double series after multiplying $\frac1{\zeta(s+z-2)}$? I did not get this. Could you clarify?

Comment: and how does $\frac1{\zeta(s+s-2)}$ have a double pole at $s=2$? It is just $\frac1{\zeta(2)}$ right?

Comment: oh! ok, the poles are from $\zeta(s-1)$, got it!

Comment: and why is $\sum_{m,n}\frac1{m^2n^2}\neq \zeta(4)$ The summands are positive right?

Comment: ??? $\sum_{m,n} m^{-2} n^{-2} =(\sum_{m} m^{-2} )(\sum_n n^{-2})= \zeta(2)^2$

Comment: ok! so that was silly of me! anyways, I think you are a professional analytic number theorist?

Comment: I study maths for free. Here there are a lot of teachers, but the researchers and pure maths (under)graduate teachers are mainly on mathoverflow.net